# exited: {bad_return, {{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]}

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am using erlang R14B01 with Ejabberd, when I start Ejabberd on my Lion, it shows errors, who can tell me the reason, thanks!
I have hosts config `{hosts, ["localhost"]}.`

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2012-09-18 23:35:10 ===
    application: ejabberd
    exited: {bad_return,
                {{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                 {'EXIT',
                     {badarg,
                         [{erlang,port_control,
                              [stringprep_port,2,"localhost"],
                              []},
                          {stringprep,control,2,[]},
                          {jlib,nodeprep,1,[]},
                          {ejabberd_config,normalize_hosts,2,[]},
                          {ejabberd_config,add_hosts_to_option,2,[]},
                          {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1197}]},
                          {ejabberd_config,load_file,1,[]},
                          {ejabberd_config,start,0,[]}]}}}}
    type: temporary

=ERROR REPORT==== 2012-09-18 23:44:32 ===
Error in process <0.2102.0> on node 'ejabberd@localhost' with exit value: {{case_clause,{error,{open_error,-16}}},[{ejabberd_app,init,0,[]}]}


=INFO REPORT==== 2012-09-18 23:44:32 ===
    application: ejabberd
    exited: {bad_return,
                {{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                 {'EXIT',
                     {badarg,
                         [{erlang,port_control,
                              [stringprep_port,2,"localhost"],
                              []},
                          {stringprep,control,2,[]},
                          {jlib,nodeprep,1,[]},
                          {ejabberd_config,normalize_hosts,2,[]},
                          {ejabberd_config,add_hosts_to_option,2,[]},
                          {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1197}]},
                          {ejabberd_config,load_file,1,[]},
                          {ejabberd_config,start,0,[]}]}}}}
    type: temporary
```

Answer (score 1):

From the crash report, the problem seems to be on stringprep,  that is a driver (written in C, linked into ejabberd VM).  For my experience, most of the times these kind of errors arise when ejabberd is compiled with one erlang version,  but tried to run with another one.  Try to make a clean recompilation with R14B01